# How can i remove blank xmlns attribute from thirdparty business service response message

Tags: xml, oracle, web-services, xslt, soa

I have third party service. An empty xmlns value is returned in one of the elements of this service

Here is the business service response

[image]

As you see, IthalatBeyannameler element has a blank xmlns="" thats why xslt transforming not working.

Here is my xslt

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <tns:KalemMarkaList>
     <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:AntrepoCikisDigerResponse/ns0:AntrepoCikisDigerResult/ns0:IthalatBeyannameler/ns0:IthalatBeyanname">
        <tns:KalemMarka>
           <tns:Sasi/>
           <tns:MaviRef>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:MaviRef"/>
           </tns:MaviRef>
           <tns:MusteriIsNo>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:MusteriIsNo"/>
           </tns:MusteriIsNo>
           <tns:Yil>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Yil"/>
           </tns:Yil>
        </tns:KalemMarka>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </tns:KalemMarkaList>
```

how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you see, IthalatBeyannameler element has a blank xmlns="" thats why xslt transforming not working.

No. Your transformation is not working because you ignore it. You try to select:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:AntrepoCikisDigerResponse/ns0:AntrepoCikisDigerResult/ns0:IthalatBeyannameler/ns0:IthalatBeyanname">
```

when you should be doing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:AntrepoCikisDigerResponse/ns0:AntrepoCikisDigerResult/IthalatBeyannameler/IthalatBeyanname">
```

that is remove the `ns0` prefix when addressing elements which are in no-namespace due to the no-namespace declaration.

For the same reason you need to change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:MaviRef"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MaviRef"/>
```

and likewise for the other two `xsl:value-of` instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If the `IthalatBeyannamele` element (and its descendants) are supposed to be in namespace http://tempuri.org/ then you need to fix [or persuade the supplier to fix] the code that put them in the null namespace. (Is there a specification of the XML returned by this API, and if so, what does it say?)

On the other hand, if the elements are supposed to be in the null namespace then you need to fix your stylesheet to process them in that namespace.

Note that its not the namespace (un-)declaration that is your problem, it is the fact that the elements are in the wrong namespace.